# How to select Column value as Column name with conditions in SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL. I have a table 'Customers' and it looks like this.

[image]

I would like to select 'Gender' AS Gender Column and 'Age' as Age column which would be like this.

[image]

I've tried several ways but it still doesn't show what I need. Please help me.

Comment: Which database system is it?

Comment: Why is the table not set up like the second example in the first place?

Comment: The database is MySql.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way to go about it is to use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN field = 'Gender' THEN value END) gender,
       MAX(CASE WHEN field = 'Age' THEN value END) age
  FROM customers
 GROUP BY name
```

The other way (if you're interested only in these two columns) would be

```
SELECT c1.name, c1.value gender, c2.value age
  FROM customers c1 JOIN customers c2
    ON c1.name = c2.name
   AND c1.field = 'Gender'
   AND c2.field = 'Age';
```

Assumption is that both Gender and Age exist for each Name. It it's not the case then use an `OUTER JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN` like so

```
SELECT n.name, c1.value gender, c2.value age
  FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT name
    FROM customers
) n LEFT JOIN customers c1
    ON n.name = c1.name AND c1.field = 'Gender' 
    LEFT JOIN customers c2
    ON n.name = c2.name AND c2.field = 'Age';
```

Output:

```
|   NAME | GENDER | AGE |
|--------|--------|-----|
| Angela | Female |  28 |
|  Davis |   Male |  30 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c73934/5)** demo

Answer (score 5):

I have not tested this, but give something like this a try:

```
Select c.Name,
    (Select c2.Value from customers c2 Where c2.Name = c.Name And c2.Field = 'Gender') as Gender,
    (Select c2.Value from customers c2 Where c2.Name = c.Name And c2.Field = 'Age') as Age
From Customers c
Group By c.Name
```

PS I apologize for the awful formatting...had to type this from my phone.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid it might duplicate your data as each name shows up twice. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score -4):

You can use `SHOW COLUMNS FROM Customers` to get the name of the columns

Then just use `SELECT * FROM Customers` to retrieve the data

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.